# Cast to multiple Chromecasts from the same computer

Tags: google-chrome, google, chrome-extensions, chromecast

Is it possible to cast either the same tab or different tabs from one mac to multiple Chromecasts on the same network? It seems like when you open another tab and try and cast that to a different Chromecast it stops casting to the first Chromecast.

The Extension is in Beta but it would be very nice to cast to multiple Chromecasts at the same time!

Comment: on what hardware with what os x?

Comment: Macbook Air 2014, Yosemite.